# How to fix pages cut off when printing use mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, angular

first of all I use angular, I have create setting for printing HTML use window.print() and styling with style.scss. everything is OK when print with Chrome browser, but for Firefox browser is not. On firefox, the pages is cut off, Where do I need update styling code for fix that?

I has a tableComponent.html + tableComponent.scss for content table I will print. I have add overflow for selected content like this:

**tableComponent.scss**

```
#selectedHTML {
display: block;
height: 0px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

but not work

**tableComponent.scss**

```
#selectedHTML {
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

but not work

I expect the content pages is not cut off on Firefox

Comment: I suggest you set `max-width: 100%` to prevent block follow horizontaly over the max visible/printable area, and force it break block line as normal.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented may be one of your problem is that you not limited the container, Or may be a simple wrapping problem.

May this help you:

Sample CSS:

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    /*
      nowrap make it force cut off
      pre-line make it force wapr
    */
    white-space: pre-line;/**/
}    
.border.item {
    min-width: 558px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 79px;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
          <div class="border item" ></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where text from articles was getting cut off and I found `display: block` instead of `flex` or `grid` for the parent div fixed the issue.